# Web Api Controller not found error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

Not sure what i am missing here. I have Web API controller but when i call the api using

```
 http://localhost:10843/api/Lookup/GetData
```

I get error

```
[HttpException]: The controller for path &#39;/api/Lookup/GetData&#39; was not found or does not implement IController.
```

Here is the implementation. Note that im using Unity for Dependancy Injection so i am assuming IMyService and IMapper will be provided by Unity at run time.

```
        public class LookupController : ApiController
        {
            IMyService _service = null;
            IMapper _mapper = null;


            public LookupController(IMyService service, IMapper mapper)
            {
                _service = service;
                _mapper = mapper;
            }

            public IEnumerable<MyModel> GetData()
            {
                var result _service.GetData();
                return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<MyDodel>>(result);
            }
         }



        public static class WebApiConfig
        {
            public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
            {
                // Web API configuration and services

                // Web API routes
                config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

                config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                    name: "DefaultApi",
                    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/id",
                    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                );
            }
        }
```

Also i wanted to know do i need default constructor?

Comment: Should be `routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",`

Comment: Have you try to remove the parameters from your controller's contructor, just for test purpose? Because, if it works, the problem is your IoC container configuration

Comment: Have you registered you other services with the IoC?

Comment: @Stephen Muecke is correct